# Google Maps API image

Tags: google-maps

How to get the image when searched address in google maps?

While searching addresses in google search it displays the address, rating and image in the left side. I am using the google map api in my application, it's getting only Address and rating,but not image.

Can you provide your feedback,how to get images by using google maps api.

[image: How to get images from google maps api]

Answer (score 1):

In the Google Places API, you can use the [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) and [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) to get a photos of a specific place.

You can see a `photo_reference` here that is used to identify the photo when you perform a Photo request.

Now, you can use the [Place Photo Requests](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos#place_photo_requests) to get the image of the **photoreference** that you get.

Here is the sample request.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CnRtAAAATLZNl354RwP_9UKbQ_5Psy40texXePv4oAlgP4qNEkdIrkyse7rPXYGd9D_Uj1rVsQdWT4oRz4QrYAJNpFX7rzqqMlZw2h2E2y5IKMUZ7ouD_SlcHxYq1yL4KbKUv3qtWgTK0A6QbGh87GB3sscrHRIQiG2RrmU_jF4tENr9wGS_YxoUSSDrYjWmrNfeEHSGSc3FyhNLlBU&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```